# How to store a PDF file or blob in local/session storage in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, blob

I'm trying to store pdf files in local/session storage in Angular.

What I have found out till now is that we can convert it into a string by encoding it into base64 and store it. However I'm not sure how we can retrieve the initial blob we had.

Does anyone know any useful library to make the conversion easier? Or have any relevant snippet?

Comment: Actually we will not end up using it. We only need to show it to the users. So slow load won't affect much.

Answer (score 1):

I use the below base64Decoder helper to convert a base64 string into an ArrayBuffer

```
/* eslint-disable no-bitwise */
const chars =
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

// Use a lookup table to find the index.
const lookup = typeof Uint8Array === 'undefined' ? [] : new Uint8Array(256);
for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  lookup[chars.charCodeAt(i)] = i;
}

export const encode = (arraybuffer: ArrayBuffer): string => {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  let i;
  const len = bytes.length;
  let base64 = '';

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 3) {
    base64 += chars[bytes[i] >> 2];
    base64 += chars[((bytes[i] & 3) << 4) | (bytes[i + 1] >> 4)];
    base64 += chars[((bytes[i + 1] & 15) << 2) | (bytes[i + 2] >> 6)];
    base64 += chars[bytes[i + 2] & 63];
  }

  if (len % 3 === 2) {
    base64 = base64.substring(0, base64.length - 1) + '=';
  } else if (len % 3 === 1) {
    base64 = base64.substring(0, base64.length - 2) + '==';
  }

  return base64;
};

export const decode = (base64: string): ArrayBuffer => {
  let bufferLength = base64.length * 0.75;
  const len = base64.length;
  let i;
  let p = 0;
  let encoded1;
  let encoded2;
  let encoded3;
  let encoded4;

  if (base64[base64.length - 1] === '=') {
    bufferLength--;
    if (base64[base64.length - 2] === '=') {
      bufferLength--;
    }
  }

  const arraybuffer = new ArrayBuffer(bufferLength);
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    encoded1 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i)];
    encoded2 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 1)];
    encoded3 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 2)];
    encoded4 = lookup[base64.charCodeAt(i + 3)];

    bytes[p++] = (encoded1 << 2) | (encoded2 >> 4);
    bytes[p++] = ((encoded2 & 15) << 4) | (encoded3 >> 2);
    bytes[p++] = ((encoded3 & 3) << 6) | (encoded4 & 63);
  }

  return arraybuffer;
};
```

Using this helper, your code could maybe look like:

```
import { decode } from '../path-to-your-base64-decoder'

const base64Pdf = // get base64 string pdf
const pdfBlob = new Blob([decode(base64Pdf)]);
```